# My for loop operating on each timestamp in high frequency data is ineffective

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I am using R to calculate whole lake temperatures at every timestamp from the open water season.

I have loggers at various depths logging temperature every 10 minutes.

Each data frame for each lake has over 100k entries with over 10k different timestamps.

This is how I have solved this using a for loop. However, the code is extremely inefficient and it takes a couple of hours per lake depending how deep it is (deeper lakes have more loggers).

Example below resembles what my data look like. Running the script on the example goes fast, but takes hours on real data.

There should be a more effective way of doing this, with some apply-family function but idk how.

```
    library(rLakeAnalyzer)
    
date <- c("2000-01-01 00:00:00","2000-01-01 00:00:00","2000-01-01 00:00:00",
          "2000-01-01 00:10:00","2000-01-01 00:10:00","2000-01-01 00:10:00",
          "2000-01-01 00:20:00","2000-01-01 00:20:00","2000-01-01 00:20:00")
depth <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
temp <- c(20,12,9,14,12,11,10,7,4)

dt <- as.data.frame(cbind(temp,depth,date)) #example data frame

dptd <- c(0,1,2,3) #example depth
dpta <- c(5000,2500,1250,625) #example area per depth

datelist <- levels(as.factor(dt$date)) #'for each date in the frame...'

ldf <- list() #list to store every row for the new data frame
for(i in 1:length(datelist)){
  print(i) #to check how fast it operates
  lek <- dt[grepl(datelist[i],dt$date),] #take every date in dt
  temp <- whole.lake.temperature(wtr=lek$temp,depths=lek$depth,bthA=dpta,bthD=dptd) #function 
  date <- datelist[i] 
  ldf[[i]] <- as.data.frame(cbind(temp,date)) #make a dataframe in list with 1 row and 2 col
}

ldf <- bind_rows(ldf) #convert list of data frames to a complete data frame
ldf$temp <- as.numeric(ldf$temp)
ldf$date <- as.POSIXct(ldf$date)

plot(ldf$date,ldf$temp) #woala, I have a dataframe with the whole lake temp at every timestamp
```

Comment: you could find out which operation is taking time with `profvis` package, and depending on the result consider parallelization with for example `foreach` package

Comment: I see. I tried the loop with only 'lek <- dt[grepl(datelist[i],dt$date),]' and this command takes ages without even doing any operation. I guess that is where parallelization comes into place, where it does the operation on every single date simultaneously? Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `data.table`, grouping by `date`, and then applying the `whole.lake.temperature` function:

```
library(rLakeAnalyzer)
library(data.table)
date <- c("2000-01-01 00:00:00","2000-01-01 00:00:00","2000-01-01 00:00:00",
      "2000-01-01 00:10:00","2000-01-01 00:10:00","2000-01-01 00:10:00",
      "2000-01-01 00:20:00","2000-01-01 00:20:00","2000-01-01 00:20:00")
depth <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
temp <- c(20,12,9,14,12,11,10,7,4)

dt <- as.data.frame(cbind(temp,depth,date)) #example data frame

dptd <- c(0,1,2,3) #example depth
dpta <- c(5000,2500,1250,625) #example area per depth

results <- setDT(dt)[,by=date,
                     .(temp=whole.lake.temperature(wtr=temp,
                                                   depths=depth,
                                                   bthA=dpta,
                                                   bthD=dptd))]
```

It's hard to tell if it speeds things up without trying it out on your whole dataset. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hello. This code gave me what I want in less than 1 second. Excellent!